# List to object with default values in Typescript

Tags: typescript

The following function (without type declaration) behaves as expected in Javascript, but Typescript is raising the error `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter` for `...keysArray`.

```
const arrayToMap = (keysArray: string[], defaultValue: any) => {
  const object = Object.assign(...keysArray.map((k) => ({ [k]: defaultValue })));
  return object;
};
```

How can this be solved? I already tried to put the spread operator in the function arguments without luck.

In Javascript:

```js
const arrayToMap = (keysArray, defaultValue) => {
  const object = Object.assign(...keysArray.map((k) => ({ [k]: defaultValue })));
  return object;
};

console.log(arrayToMap(['a', 'b', 'c'], false))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the overload that accepts an array has the signature `assign(target: object, ...sources: any[]): any`. You can't spread `any[]` to `[object,...any[]]` because `[object,...any[]]` requires at least one element and `any[]` could have 0 elements.

This could be one solution:

```
const arrayToMap = (keysArray: string[], defaultValue: any) => {
  const object = Object.assign({}, ...keysArray.map((k) => ({ [k]: defaultValue })));
  return object;
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAngFRAWTgBxgXhgAoBrAUxQgEElUAuGaBASzAHMBtAXQBoYATMgDM4AVwA2UAGpxxosgzhgUASgIA+GAG8AsACgYMUJFggARgCsywWIQDyl61AB0cCBGZswRLQF8+zoHklDTIKM4AtrhEpGr4mj4wHCRcDIIiEtKy8jC+KvkA3PqGCGRQoghgMOZWNkV6vgVAA)

Answer (score 0):

For **primitive data types**' default value, follow below syntax

```js
const numList = new Array(5).fill(0)

console.log(numList)
console.log('Total items: ' + numList.length)
```

For **objects**'s default value, follow below syntax

```js
const objList = new Array(5).fill(0).map(()=> ({ var1: 22, var2: 33 }))

console.log(objList)
console.log('Total items: ' + objList.length)
```

Comment: Don't post the same answer to multiple questions. If the questions are duplicates of each other, vote to close as such.